# Synonym for search term

Tags: feature-request

Like we have tag synonyms, it would be good to have search keyword synonyms too.

Are you looking for **capacitors**, **cap**, **caps** or a single **capacitor**? The search results vary with each. Is it a **Solar** or **Photovoltaic** maybe someone wrote **photo-voltaic** cell?

There are questions that discuss **Chebychev** filters and there are questions that discuss **Chebyshev** filters. And how many people know how to spell **Schottky** diode correctly? Fuzzy matching like [agrep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/agrep) anyone?

Too often (in my opinion) I loose track of answers/questions just because I am searching for a slightly varying spelled term. The disadvantage of Google is that it is pretty hard to just search for answers on a single stack.

Comment: Can you not use a Google search like "site:electronics.stackexchange.com search term here" ?

Comment: @David Google is not aware of many synonyms and typing the site:.... is not know to everyone and prone to typos.